# Grails many-to-many concern

Tags: grails

Hello everybody i try to add recipes and one recipe has many condiments. also one condiment can belong to many recipes.
and a condimant can have some additional values like amount and the entity of the amount.

I get the following error in my Bootstrap.groovy (using GGTS , Grails 2.4.4, mysql)

The error:

```
Message: No signature of method: marvelonlinerezepte.Zutat.addToRezept() is applicable for argument types: (marvelonlinerezepte.Rezept) values: [Bratwurst mit Sauerkraut]
Possible solutions: addToRezepte(java.lang.Object)
    Line | Method
->>   32 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

The Bootstrap:

```
import org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout;

import marvelonlinerezepte.Zutat
import marvelonlinerezepte.Rezept
import marvelonlinerezepte.MmRezepteZutaten

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        Zutat sauerkraut = new Zutat()
        Zutat bratwurst = new Zutat()
        Zutat rapsoel = new Zutat()

        sauerkraut.bezeichnung = 'Sauerkraut'
        bratwurst.bezeichnung = 'Bratwurst'
        rapsoel.bezeichnung = 'Rapsöl nativ'

        sauerkraut.save()
        bratwurst.save()
        rapsoel.save()

        Rezept bratwurstMitSauerkraut = new Rezept()

        bratwurstMitSauerkraut.name = 'Bratwurst mit Sauerkraut'
        bratwurstMitSauerkraut.zubereitung = 'Bratwurst in Öl anbraten bis Sie schön braun sind. Sauerkraut in einem Topf langsam erwärmen. Servieren und FERTIG :)'
        bratwurstMitSauerkraut.zubereitungszeitInMinuten = 15
        bratwurstMitSauerkraut.kcalProPerson = 350.55F  

        bratwurstMitSauerkraut.save(failOnError:true,flush:true)

        /*here comes the error*/
        sauerkraut.addToRezept(bratwurstMitSauerkraut)
        bratwurst.addToRezept(bratwurstMitSauerkraut)

        bratwurstMitSauerkraut.save(flush:true)


    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

my domain classes:

```
 package marvelonlinerezepte

class Rezept {

    String name
    String zubereitung
    Integer zubereitungszeitInMinuten
    Float kcalProPerson

    static hasMany = [zutaten:Zutat]

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false, blank:false)
        zubereitung(nullable:true, blank:true, size:50..10000)
        kcalProPerson(nullable:true,blank:true,setScale:2)
        zubereitungszeitInMinuten(nullable:true,blank:true)

    }

    static mapping = {
        zubereitung type: 'text'
        zutaten joinTable: [name: "mm_rezepte_zutaten", key: 'rezept_id']
     }

    String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }
}


    package marvelonlinerezepte

class Zutat {

    String bezeichnung

    static belongsTo = Rezept

    static hasMany = [rezepte:Rezept]

    static constraints = {
        bezeichnung(nullable:false, blank:false)

    }
    static mapping = {  
        rezepte joinTable: [name: "mm_rezepte_zutaten", key: 'zutat_id']
    }

    String toString(){
        return this.bezeichnung;
    }

}


    package marvelonlinerezepte

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class MmRezepteZutaten implements Serializable {

    Rezept rezept
    Zutat zutat

    Float menge = 1
    String einheit = "g"

    static constraints = {
        menge min:0.01F
        einheit inList: ["g", "l","ml", "EL", "TL","stck","prise"]
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'mm_rezepte_zutaten'
        version false
        id composite: ["rezept","zutat"]
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof MmRezepteZutaten)) {
            return false
        }

        other.rezept?.id == rezept?.id &&
        other.zutat?.id == zutat?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (rezept) builder.append(rezept.id)
        if (zutat) builder.append(zutat.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static MmRezepteZutaten get(long rezeptId, long zutatId) {
        find 'from mm_rezepte_zutaten where rezept.id=:rezeptId and zutat.id=:zutatId',
            [rezeptId: rezeptId, zutatId: zutatId]
    }

    static MmRezepteZutaten create(Rezept rezept, Zutat zutat, boolean flush = false) {
        new MmRezepteZutaten(rezept: rezept, zutat: zutat).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(Rezept rezept, Zutat zutat, boolean flush = false) {
        MmRezepteZutaten instance = MmRezepteZutaten.findByRezeptAndZutat(rezept, zutat)
        instance ? instance.delete(flush: flush) : false
    }

    static void removeAll(Rezept rezept) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM mm_rezepte_zutaten WHERE rezept=:rezept', [rezept: rezept]
    }

    static void removeAll(Zutat zutat) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM mm_rezepte_zutaten WHERE zutat=:zutat', [zutat: zutat]
    }


}
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the relationships simpler. This may be the problem. You don't actually need to have the belongsTo. And I'm pretty sure that adding it will mean that one condiment belongs to only one recipe.

Try the following:

```
class Zutat {

    String bezeichnung

}

class Rezept {

    String name
    String zubereitung
    Integer zubereitungszeitInMinuten
    Float kcalProPerson

    static hasMany = [zutaten:Zutat]
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are declaring it the wrong way around:

Here are a few pages and to guide:
https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testads5/blob/master/grails-app/domain/ajaxdependancyselectexample/MyBorough.groovy
https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testads5/blob/master/grails-app/domain/ajaxdependancyselectexample/MyCity.groovy

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/testads5/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy#L112-L130

```
Rezept bratwurstMitSauerkraut = new Rezept()
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.name = 'Bratwurst mit Sauerkraut'
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.zubereitung = 'Bratwurst in Öl anbraten bis Sie schön braun sind. Sauerkraut in einem Topf langsam erwärmen. Servieren und FERTIG :)'
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.zubereitungszeitInMinuten = 15
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.kcalProPerson = 350.55F  
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.save()

Zutat sauerkraut = new Zutat(bezeichnung : 'Sauerkraut')
sauerkraut.addToRezepte(bratwurstMitSauerkraut)
sauerkraut.save(flush:true)
```

Try something like above, has not been tested but kind of is more similar to how I did that example show in the links. Also notice Rezepte its the actual alias you have given it but starting as upper case, it will appear like an unknown field.

Answer (score 0):

hi everybody and many thanks for the answers.
i could fix the problem on my own and here is the code that really works for me:

in bootstrap i changed this:

```
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.addToZutaten(bratwurst)
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.addToZutaten(sauerkraut)                 
bratwurstMitSauerkraut.save(flush:true)
```

and then he complained a mysql error about not having d default value for all the extra attributes in MmRezepteZutaten . This coud be fixed like this:

```
package marvelonlinerezepte

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DefaultValueLoaderDecorator;

class MmRezepteZutaten implements Serializable {

    Rezept rezept
    Zutat zutat

    Float menge = 1.0f
    String einheit = "g"

    Float preis = 0.0f

    String laden
    Integer reihenfolge

    static constraints = {
        menge min:0.01F
        einheit inList: ["g", "l","ml", "EL", "TL","stck","prise"]
        laden inList: ["Aldi","Edeka"]
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'mm_rezepte_zutaten'
        version false
        id composite: ["rezept","zutat"]

        menge defaultValue: "1.0"
        einheit defaultValue: "'g'"
        preis defaultValue: "0.0"
        laden defaultValue: "'Aldi'"
        reihenfolge defaultValue: "0"
    }


}
```